# Inserting values to an empty/existing column [SQL,R]

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

I have a database schema called db, and i want to export data from R into a mysql table called db.Info. I tried the query below, but it can only insert one value at the time. Is there a way to export multiple values into an empty/existing column in a mysql table?

dbSendQuery(db, "INSERT INTO db.Info (`id.Info`,`R1`, `R2`)
VALUES('6','1','2');")

Comment: use `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax.

Comment: `INSERT INTO db.Info (id.Info, R1, R2) VALUES ('6', '1', '2'), ('6', '1', '2'), ('6', '1', '2')` would insert three identical rows.  There may be easier ways than constructing a string with your query, however.  What is the source of data in R?  A data frame?  list?